# using percentage in eval() not working

Tags: javascript

im making a simple calculator and im building it using eval() function , everything works fine except percentage button "%" , is there any way to eval() percentage from a string?
here is my simple code.

Here is my JS.

```
var val = document.getElementById("ReadOut").value;
function equal(){
  var fin = eval(val);
  return document.getElementById("ReadOut").value = fin;
}
```

and this is my HTML.

```
    <form id="keyPad" action="">
  <table width="500px" height="400px" border="2">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td colspan="3">
      <input id="ReadOut" type="text" size="1" value="">
    </td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <input id="equal" type="button" value="=" onclick="calc()">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="seven" type="button" value="7" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '7'">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="eight" type="button" value="8" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '8'">
    </td> 
    <td>
      <input id="nine" type="button" value="9" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '9'">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="plus" type="button" value="+" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '+'">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="minus" type="button" value="-" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '-'">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="four" type="button" value="4" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '4'">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="five" type="button" value="5" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '5'">
    </td> 
    <td>
      <input id="six" type="button" value="6" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '6'">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="multiply" type="button" value="*" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '*'">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="divide" type="button" value="/" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '/'">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input id="one" type="button" value="1" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '1'">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="two" type="button" value="2" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '2'">
    </td> 
    <td>
      <input id="three" type="button" value="3" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '3'" >
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="clear" type="reset" value="C">
    </td>
    <td>
      <input id="percent" type="button" value="%" onclick="keyPad.ReadOut.value += '%'">
    </td>
  </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

dolorem ipsum, quia dolor sit amet consectetur adipisci[ng] velit, sed quia non numquam.

Comment: [`%` in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) is probably not what you think it is.

Comment: `eval()` is dangerous and can impede performance. It should absolutely never be used on user input because of the risks of a cross-site scripting attack. `eval()` is rarely, if ever needed to solve a programming issue and if you find that it is the only way, then you need to re-think your solution. Additionally, tables should not be used for layout, nor should inline HTML event attributes (`onclick`, etc.) be used. I would go back and redesign this entire setup.

Comment: https://codepen.io/ckm100/pen/dPLyjZ

Answer (score 1):

Pass `0.5` instead of `50%`.
N.B: Using `eval()` is very risky. `eval()` should not be used on the value from user input.