# Javascript eval()Javascript work with the percentage symbol (%) as a percentage but not as a reminder

Tags: javascript, html, properties, eval, calculator

How do I make the eval() in Javascript work with the percentage symbol (%) as a percentage but not as a reminder

I want  to be able to let the eval() work with percentages as 1/100 not as a reminder

Comment: `eval` evaluates javascript, javascript does not support 'percentage' values, nor does eval.

Comment: read this pls https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46980774/using-percentage-in-eval-not-working

Answer (score 0):

As percentage is defined as `* 0.01`,

```
function evalWithPercentage(s) {
  return eval(s.replaceAll('%', ' * 0.01'))
}
console.log( evalWithPercentage('10% + 150%') )
//> 1.6
```

Comment: `10%` of what? ;)

Comment: 10% of 1. A percent is a unit equal to `0.01`.